# Python: Replace 'one-line if's with ternary if, good idea or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a code I'm currently maintaining, I often see a 'one-line if' construct such as this:

```
if self.verbose >= 1:
    print("Starting...")
```

I want to replace it with:

```
print("Starting...") if self.verbose >= 1 else None
```

Or even:

```
self.verbose >= 1 and print("Starting...")
```

Is this a good idea or a bad idea, in terms of performance and/or maintainability?

**EDIT:** Although allowed, I do NOT want to make it into a *totally* one-liner, e.g.,
`if self.verbose >=1: print("Starting...")`

Comment: That's a bad idea from a readability and maintainability standpoint. Performance will not be impacted.

Comment: Why would you want to replace it with a one liner?

Comment: @user5061 because the complete code is peppered with these kind of `if` constructs, it made the source overly long vertically. Personally, this make it difficult for me to follow the code.

Comment: Then put the "long" version in a function and call it with a one-liner.

Comment: I actually find the pattern: ``self.verbose and print(...)`` to be quite readable iHMO :)

Comment: @JamesMills me too! But I do understand that it's totally subjective... so that's why I'd like to gather the community's thoughts about this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the performance of both cases but the first is more readable!

For more details read the [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) about Conditional Expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why would you do that. I think all the alternatives you proposed are less readable. (but that's subjective of course)

How about removing the condition in general? This would at least remove the repetition of `if`.

```
def print_verbose(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.verbose>=1:
        print(*args, **kwargs)

...
self.print_verbose("Starting...")
```

Or even migrate to using the `logging` module which already has the support for different logging levels. With configured logging this becomes: (provided that `logger` is created for this module via `logging.getLogger()`)

```
logger.verbose("Starting")
```

Regarding performance... if the way you write `if`s actually matters for performance in this program, then Python itself may not be a good idea ;) (difference will be measured in nanoseconds, it most likely doesn't matter)